# How to sort posts by modified date when using pagination?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-paginator

I add a 'modified' date to my posts and make them sorted from new to old by modified date instead of  posted date. Make people notice the update of posts.

I have ymal for posts , like this:

```
---
title: Mytitle
posted: 2020-06-29
modified: 2020-07-29
....
```

And the following code works well:

```
{% assign my_sorted_list = site.posts | sort:"modified" %}
{% for post in my_sorted_list %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

But when I turn on the [jekyll-paginate](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/) in my `_config.yml`, it is sorted by the posted date again.

Is there any way I can sort by modified date when I turn on the pagination? I have tried a few methods but nothing seems to work. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this function is not supported. Because I found this [pull request](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-paginate/pull/31). This request aims to that paginator can sort posts by modified date. And this request is not merged yet.

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem? I am having the same one.